# Autogenerate XSL file

Tags: c#, xslt

I have a mapper utility that map the input XML nodes to another nodes (it doesn't use XSLT). At runtime, it walks the XML nodes and converts it. Glorified node to node converter but not efficient and has a performance barrier that we cannot overcome. The good part is that it writes a definition file that lists inbound XML elements and its corresponding conversion names. I would like to write a tool in .NET, that would read this definition file and auto-generates a XSLT with it. Once it generates the XSLT, I can compile it using XSLTC and include it using reflection in my Web apps for runtime conversions. Any ideas, guidance, suggestions or tools available to make this happen is much appreciated

Below is an over simplified example

```
<order><order_id>12345</order_id><customer>Cust1</customer></order>
```

definition file

```
[Header]
order=customer_order
[Fields]
order_id=order_number
customer=customer_number
```

Tool runs the conversion using the definition file and generate the below xml after conversion

```
<customer_order><order_number>12345</order_number><customer_number>Cust1</customer_number></customer_order>
```

Comment: Probably already know that, but just in case ,make sure the current utility - or the one you build - use stringbuilder class, not concatenating strings. Can make 100x difference (glorified guess but I'm betting not far off).

Comment: @FastAl - thanks for your response. StringBuilder is already in place but the problem is the definition file is read at runtime. These files can be huge, because the XMLs are large. Both CPU and memory usage just spikes up. As a sample we just picked 1 XML, wrote a XSLT, compiled it and applied to the inbound XML. The process took milliseconds to complete without pressuring CPU and memory.

Comment: just my two cents: maybe you can modify your tool to produce some more xml style output `<order new="customer_order"><order_id new="order_number"/><customer new=customer_number/></order>` then you can write an xslt which writes itself a xslt for the right transformation (this is possible)!

Answer (score 0):

Interesting.  From your responses, it's not entirely clear which part is slow, but I agree XSLT will likely product a much faster result for a couple reasons.

- XSLT will locate rules for each node faster, especially important if there a lots of rules
- XSLT will construct the resulting XML very efficiently.

An XSLT approach would start and build from an identity template (that copies one XML to another), and then add templates to convert as needed.  You just need to walk through your rules and create the  for each one.

Here's sample identity template, with the 3 rules added.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<!-- order=customer_order -->
<xsl:template match="order">
    <customer_order><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></customer_order>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="order_id">
    <order_number><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></order_number>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="customer">
    <customer_number><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></customer_number>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And the resulting XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<customer_order>
    <order_number>12345</order_number>
    <customer_number>Cust1</customer_number>
</customer_order>
```

Good luck